# Syntax error, unexpected 'form' (T_STRING), expecting ')'

Tags: laravel-6

I tried to make a form inside a modal with Bootstrap but I get errors.

> Facade\Ignition\Exceptions\ViewException syntax error, unexpected
>   'form' (T_STRING), expecting ')' (View:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\invuya\resources\views\petambak\index.blade.php)

http://localhost/invuya/public/petambak

This is the source code of the error:

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Form Petambak</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            </form action="{{route('petambak.store)}}" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Nama</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="Nama" id="name">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Simpan</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe problem is in line `</form action="{{route('petambak.store)}}" method="post">` because of missin pair quote after `petambak.store`?

Also `localhost` is available only from your machine

Comment: thanks you ,for your help . it work now, but i have one more issue, can you help me deal with it

Comment: @hendry_len It depends on the issue. IMO it's better to post a new question

Comment: got it, i will post that issue soon. thank for the help

Comment: To mark an answer as correct you simply need to click the green check image